# To check IP address range

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, force.com-sites, site.com

I am trying to check IP address range. Where we provide a IP address to check whether it lies between start and end IP address.

I am using custom setting to set start and end IP address.

Only if site guest user is in between the start and end IP address, he can proceed for further flow.

What I have implemented so far

```
String ipAdress = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP');
// Quering Custom setting
List<Network_IP__c> objNtwIP = [SELECT id,Start_IP_Address__c,End_IP_Address__c FROM Network_IP__c];
for(Network_IP__c netIP : objNtwIP){

    if(netIP.Start_IP_Address__c >= ipAdress && netIP.End_IP_Address__c <= ipAdress){  
        if(userid !=null && userid.length()>0){
            // Logic
        }else{
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Inside');
            apexpages.addmessage(myMsg);
            return null;
        }

    }else{
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, 'Not found');
            apexpages.addmessage(myMsg);
            return null;
    }   
}
```

Any help!!!

Comment: it would be nice to tell us what is the problem with your code, what is working or not, so that we can focus on a way to solve it instead of trying to figure out what's not working ;). Also what is the type of Network_IP__c.Start_IP_Address__c and Network_IP__c.End_IP_Address__c ?

Comment: Sorting IP Addresses is a real pain in the neck.... when the octets are expressed as a base 10 number. Convert those octets to hexadecimal, and you might be able to use '>' and '<' to compare strings. OH! There's no built in `convertToHex` method... I ended up using 256 rows in a custom metadata type to handle the octet conversions for me.

Comment: @JohnThompson But IP adresses are nothing else than a number ! What's easier than compare numbers ?

Comment: @JohnThompson : to find hex string from decimal : `List<String> symbols = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''); Double num = 12345 /*whatever you want */; String hex = ''; while (true) { hex = symbols[(Integer)Math.mod((Long)(num), 16)] + hex; if (Math.floor(num/16)==0) break; num = Math.floor(num/16);  }`. I can make a question/answer if you like.

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Thanks for the input. I was weighing the pros and cons of the mathematical approach vs. the lookup approach. I ended up going with the lookup for a couple of reasons. It's quicker than the math and type conversions, and it reminds me of an embedded systems approach (and I like embedded systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your difficulty is how to compare ip addresses :

```
public class IpAddress{
    private String sIp; //ip as string
    private Double dIp; //ip as double

    private Double ipFromString(){
        String[] elts = sIp.split('\\.');
        return      Double.valueOf(elts[0]) * Math.pow(255, 3) + 
                    Double.valueOf(elts[1]) * Math.pow(255, 2) +
                    Double.valueOf(elts[2]) * Math.pow(255, 1) + //=*255
                    Double.valueOf(elts[3]) * Math.pow(255, 0);  //=*1 
    }

    public IpAddress(String ip){
        //check 'a.b.c.d' format here ?
        sIp = ip;
        dIp = this.ipFromString();
    }

    public Double asDouble(){
        return dIp;
    }

    public Boolean isInRange(IpAddress lowBoundary, IpAddress highBoundary){
        return (this.asDouble() >= lowBoundary.asDouble()) && (this.asDouble() <= highBoundary.asDouble());
    }
}

IpAddress ip = new IpAddress('192.168.10.11');
System.debug(ip.isInRange(new IpAddress('192.168.0.0'), new IpAddress('192.168.255.255'))); //true
ip = new IpAddress('10.0.0.1');
System.debug(ip.isInRange(new IpAddress('192.168.0.0'), new IpAddress('192.168.255.255'))); //false
```

Comment: It should be Longs not Doubles, since there is not decimal in Ip

Comment: see https://github.com/gedeef/Ip/blob/master/Ip.cls